# Is it possible to run startup scripts only for first boot on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Suppose, I have requirement to run startup scripts only on **first boot** of the vm. My vm can start/stop frequently and I don't want to run script in every boot. As per GCP doc startup scripts runs every time your instance boots up.

Answer (score 11):

Startup scripts run on each boot. There is no "run once" setting/option for Linux VMs on GCP, only for Windows VMs.

For linux, I recommend setting a [flag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156771/run-a-script-only-at-the-very-first-boot), such as a file on disk after a script runs. Then check for the existence of this flag at the start of your script and exit if it exists.

For Windows, use one of the [sysprep-specialize-scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74603137/2023941).

Comment: or the last call in your startup script could be to remove the startup script from the VM's metadata

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirement, perhaps a [sysprep-specialize-script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/windows#order_of_execution_of_windows_startup_scripts) is what you're looking for?

> ###### Order of execution of Windows startup scripts
>
> You can use multiple
> startup scripts. Startup scripts stored locally or added directly
> execute before startup scripts that are stored in Cloud Storage. The
> type of file containing the script also impacts the order of
> execution. The following table shows, based on the metadata key, the
> order of execution of Windows startup scripts.

| Metadata key | Order of execution |
| --- | --- |
| sysprep-specialize-script-ps1 | First during the initial boot |
| sysprep-specialize-script-cmd | Second during the initial boot |
| sysprep-specialize-script-bat | Third during the initial boot |
| sysprep-specialize-script-url | Fourth during the initial boot |
| windows-startup-script-ps1 | First during each boot after the initial boot |
| windows-startup-script-cmd | Second during each boot after the initial boot |
| windows-startup-script-bat | Third during each boot after the initial boot |
| windows-startup-script-url | Fourth during each boot after the initial boot |